# how to test a component if the component returns empty array in the beginning with react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

i am trying to learn react-testing-library and i got stuck at this point. I have one array that returns an empty array in the start but then i can add items inside the list. Before i add an item, component shows no data available after i add the items it shows some text and delete button next to each item. The test will be about clicking to delete button and opening a modal with this click. My test finds the delete button but it throws error saying  "Expected: 1 Received: [ ]" because it always returns "no data available" in the beginning when the component renders. Clearly its because the array returns empty in the beginning but i don't get it. here i share my component.

```
<div>
  {props.formData && props.formData.length !== 0 ? (
    props.formData.map((widget, index) => (
      <div
        id="component-item"
        className="widget-wrapper"
        key={index}
      >
        <div className="name-language">
          <p>Name: {widget.name}</p>
          <p>Language: {widget.language}</p>
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={() => toggleVisible(index)}
          type="button"
          className="delete-button"
          data-testid="component-delete"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
        {selectedItem == index ? (
          modalVisible == true ? (
            <ModalForm
              id="component-modal"
              toggleVisible={toggleVisible}
              onClick={() => handleDeleteWidget(index)}
            />
          ) : null
        ) : null}
      </div>
    ))
  ) : (
    <div>
      <p className="no-data">
        No data available
      </p>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

in the below you can see the test i wrote for it

```
test("The deleting widget asks confirmation with a modal window.", () => {

 render(<WidgetsList />);

 const deleteWidget = screen.queryAllByText("Delete");

 const modalComponent = document.querySelector("#component-modal");

 expect(deleteWidget).toBe(1);
 fireEvent.click(deleteWidget);
 expect(modalComponent).toBe(1);
});
```

i would very much appreciate if you show what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on what `modalVisible` is. Is it a state or a prop? You will need to mock that is some way to make the modal visible. Anyway, I would create at least two tests, one with `formData` empty, and other with some data. You will need to pass some mocked data to the component props, something like:

```
describe('WidgetsList', () => {
  test('no data available', () => {
    render(<WidgetsList formData={[]} />);
    expect(/No data available/).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('data available', () => {
    const mockedFormDataProp = [{ name: 'whatever', language: 'whatever' }];
    render(<WidgetsList formData={mockedFormDataProp} />);

    expect(screen.getByText(/No data available/)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Delete/));
    // attach a data-testid prop to your modal, in case there is some text
    // add test it like screen.getByText(...)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('the-modal')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: this made the job. thank you very much! have one question. i am also trying to understand how things work if i want to call two different components in one test. how does it work if i call a button in one component that changes something on another component. I couldn't find any tutorial showing this case. do you know any tutorial i can learn this how to? or if you can give me an example of it, that also would be very nice.

Comment: Hey, if that did the job you can mark it as resolved, open a new question describing the problem and what you tested. Ping me here if necessary, cheers!

Comment: i posted the question few days ago and didn't get any answer for it from anyone. here is the link for my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600471/how-to-handle-two-different-components-in-one-test-in-react-testing . if you have any answer for that, would be much appreciated :) @AdriSolid